# Three.js render white part of plain geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm trying to turn [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdwGM.jpg) `plainGeometry`, into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCQRF.png) (sort of mask).

This code works: (to sum-up, create two materials, divide the plane to segments and decide for each one which material is it with `MeshFaceMaterial`)

```
   Button.onClick(function () {

            var obj = editor.selected;
            var material = obj.material;
            var tex = material.map;
            var objHeight = obj.geometry.parameters.height;
            var objWidth = obj.geometry.parameters.width;
            var texHeight = tex.image.height;
            var texWidth = tex.image.width;

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(objWidth, objHeight, objWidth, objHeight);

            var facesNum = objHeight * objWidth * 2;
            var facesX = objWidth * 2;
            var facesInX = texWidth * 2;

            var materials = [];
            materials.push(material);
            materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ }));

            for (var i = 0; i < facesNum; i++) {
                if ((i % facesX >= objWidth - texWidth) &&
                    (i % facesX <= (facesInX + objWidth - texWidth - 1)) &&
                    (i <= (texHeight * objWidth * 2) - 1)) {
                    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
                }
                else {
                    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
                }
            }

            obj.geometry = geometry;
            obj.material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

            editor.signals.materialChanged.dispatch(obj);


        });
```

But I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to go. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did it, eventually:

```
var obj = editor.selected;
var tex = obj.material.map.;

var materials = [];
materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: tex }));
materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({}));

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

var objHeight = obj.geometry.parameters.height;
var objWidth = obj.geometry.parameters.width;
var texHeight = tex.image.height;
var texWidth = tex.image.width;

tex.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(3, 3);
tex.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(objWidth, objHeight, 3, 3);

var v = geometry.vertices;
var facesNum = geometry.faces.length;

v[1] = new THREE.Vector3(-texWidth / 2, objHeight / 2, 0);
v[2] = new THREE.Vector3(texWidth / 2, objHeight / 2, 0);
v[5] = new THREE.Vector3(-texWidth / 2, (objHeight / 2) - texHeight, 0);
v[6] = new THREE.Vector3(texWidth / 2, (objHeight / 2) - texHeight, 0);

v[9] = v[13];
v[10] = v[14];
v[4] = v[8] = v[12];
v[7] = v[11] = v[15];

for (var i = 0; i < facesNum; i++) {
    if (i !== 2 && i !== 3) geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
}

obj.material = material;
obj.geometry = geometry;

editor.signals.materialChanged.dispatch(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use an alpha channel on your texture.  You can do this with Gimp or Photoshop.

You then duplicate the mesh and push it just a tad out the axis with polygonOffsetFactor on the material.  Apply the background material to the first mesh, and the foreground material with the texture with alpha to the second.
See this fiddle [alphaTest](http://jsfiddle.net/p40yndac/12/). (you *may* need to disable cross-domain access security so the texture can load in this fiddle, chrome will allow this if you run it with the --disable-web-security flag)
The advantage to this method is that the image can be of any shape and location, and doesn't need to fit into a geometry face.

Another way, if the geometry you were using is complicated, is to use Three.DecalGeometry to cut a mesh piece out and use it shifted a bit with polygonOffsetFactor on the material. See the three.js [decals example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals) for this.

Source for the example fiddle is below:

```
var renderer;
var pointLight;
var scene;
var plane1;
var plane2;

function addPlane()
{
   var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });
   var material2;
   var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
   loader.load('http://i.imgur.com/ETdl4De.png',
     function ( texture ) {     
          var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
      map: texture,
      alphaTest: 0.7,
      polygonOffset: true,
            polygonOffsetFactor: - 4,
     });

   var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(12, 12, 12, 12);
   var geometry2 = geometry1.clone();   
   plane1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1,material1);      
   plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2,material2);      
   scene.add(plane2);
   scene.add(plane1);
    }
);

}
(function() {

    'use strict';

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);                 
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        addPlane();

    camera.position.z = 52;

    pointLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,1);
    pointLight.position.x = 11;
    pointLight.position.y = 5;
    pointLight.position.z = 25;
    scene.add(pointLight);

    var reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    var render = function() {
        reqAnimFrame(render);        
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    render();
}());
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! 
unfortunately, im looking for a solution that includes only one mesh (like rendering white the texture itself).

Comment: as I understand it the ability to use multiple textures to accomplish this did once work, but it was removed, and I dont think it works any more :(

Comment: are you familiar with ability of spliting plane to non-equal segments?
(heightSegments and widthSegments divide plane to equal parts)

Comment: I think what you want to do with non-equal segments is possible, but you would probably have to hand code it. it is possible that ThreeCSG could help. good luck!

Comment: eventually I did it with changing the vertices position. thanks a lot!